# Initiate collection in c# similar to Java anonymous class syntax

Tags: c#, collections, initializer

In Java we can initialize an ArrayList and HashMap with anonymous class declaration syntax as follows

```
public static final List<HashMap<String,String>> data
 = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(){
{
 add(
  new HashMap<String, String>()
    {{ 
      put("name", "My Name");
      put("alias", "My Name");
    }}
  );
};
```

Can we do the same in C#? in latest windows 10 programming?

Answer (score 4):

Collection initialization is also a feature of C#. The syntax to initiate a collection in C# 4.0 is similar to that you have shown.

```
private static List<Dictionary<string, string>> data = 
    new List<Dictionary<string,string>>()
    {

        new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "name", "My Name" },
                {"alias", "My Name" }
            },
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "name2", "My Name2" },
                {"alias2", "My Name2" }
            }   
    };
```

For more, please consult the [feature's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). ([Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062(v=vs.100).aspx) for the documentation specific to C# 4.0/Visual Studio 2010.)

Comment: You can leave off the parentheses when using the collection and object initializers and you're not passing arguments to a constructor. Makes for a bit cleaner syntax.

Comment: @mason I would say it's rather ambigous